# I can run npm in CMD, but can't in Conemu CMD

Tags: cmd, npm, console, conemu

I set the system variable correctly as it seems, I restarted the PC few times. What's going on? How to force Conemu to cooperate?

[image: 2 CMDs, different output]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer, of course few seconds after asking for help...
The PATH needs to be also added in the Conemu's settings. It's a little pain, if I'll need to do this every time when new variable should to be added. If you know some trick for it just comment me here...

[image: Settings]

Comment: Unbelievable. ConEmu inherits environment from the parent process (explorer.exe?). So, if you really have restarted the PC, environment must be the same. Of course, if you *did not* set `PATH` in ConEmu to fixed value like on screenshot, which is a sabotage.

Comment: Probably I unwittingly deleted the default PATH, which is "%ConEmuBaseDir%\Scripts;%PATH%;". Then after some time I encountered the problem. Adding the value like above works, but only for the npm.

Comment: The command `set PATH` in both terminals shows you the difference. ProcessExplorer helps to examine parent processes environment.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the path from the environment of conmenu settings by adding a link to nodejs is right, but deleting its previous link is not the best solution. Just add this `C:\Program Files\nodejs;` (or wherever your nodejs is located) like:

```
set PATH=%ConEmuBaseDir%\Scripts;C:\Program Files\nodejs;%PATH%
```